# Xcode always popup verifying when open

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode7-beta5

I install Xcode 7 beta, but not remove the version 6.4. And when I quit Xcode, then open my project by Xcode 7, it always show popup verifying about 3->4 minus before open the project. How can I fix that?(My Mac: 10.10.4,install Xcode beta 5)

[image]

Comment: Have you copied Xcode.app to you application directory? It should then only once do the verify process. If it keep happing make a bug report at Apple since this still beta software.

Comment: Where is the Xcode.app?

Comment: Yes where did you copy the `xcode-beta.app`. Once you downloaded the beta you open the `dmg` and then you copy the `xcode-beta.app` to you application directory.

Answer (score 2):

You can add Xcode (like any other app) to exclusions.

Open "Terminal", go to Xcode folder and add it to quarantine (see sample below).

```
cd /Applications
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine Xcode.app
```

Similiar question and answer here: [IOS Xcode Verifying Xcode.app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32071356/ios-xcode-verifying-xcode-app)