# IOS Xcode Verifying Xcode.app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, uialertview

All the times when i Open Xcode 7.0. its alert like this and takes time every time. 
I Just want solution to Completely remove this Alert from Starting of Xcode..

> At tome of open Xcode, Gives Alert -> **"Verifying XCode.app"**

[image: See Screen Shot as given Below]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Open terminal and run below commands**

> This will bypass Gatekeeper in OS X and launch Xcode quickly.

```
cd /Applications

xattr -d com.apple.quarantine Xcode.app
```

[image: Check Screen Shot]

Answer (score 16):

open terminal and type the following commend, this will help to open the Xcode in quickly

```
cd /Applications
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine Xcode.app
```

additional [reference](http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2014/Oct/msg00083.html)

Comment: thanks , I just added Screen Shot related to that. so it will become easy to understand.

Comment: haha , it is useful for future

Comment: now your problem is solved ...?

Comment: haha but for another..
and
yes, thanks friend

Comment: hmm have a nice day bro

Comment: It Did not worked for me :( !! FYI i am trying to  open Xcode 7.3 when i have already installed Xcode 7.2.. please if you can help me.

Answer (score 3):

Open terminal and enter the following:

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /path/to/Xcode.app
```